# Can anyone help me with this python program?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import csv
with open(r'C:\Users\Kunal Desai\workspace\Kunal\Kunal.csv') as csvfile:
     readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
     print(readCSV)
```

Its just printing

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Kunal Desai\workspace\Kunal\data.py", line 2, in

with open(r'C:/Users/Kunal Desai/workspace/Kunal/Kunal.csv') as csvfile:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Kunal

Desai/workspace/Kunal/Kunal.csv'

Comment: It prints exactly what it should and what you asked it to.

Comment: Uhm, did you just change the "error" to something completely different that even tells you exactly what happens? ("FileNotFoundError" should be pretty obvious)

Comment: Thank u..but now I am getting an error that the file is not found whereas the path is correctly specified...Can u plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) has a short example how to read CSVs:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

It shows, that the result of `csv.reader()` is an object you have to iterate over instead of printing it directly.

Comment: Thank u..but now I am getting an error that the file is not found whereas the path is correctly specified...Can u plz help me

Comment: Thanks a lot...now it's working fine...actually, I am using Eclipse and I had not included that file in my project. I included the file and then I printed each row by iterating as u told